# How much weight is safe up against a foundation wall?

Tags: foundation

I got 4, 55 gallon drums for rainwater collection. I want to two stacks of two drums side by side right under the gutter. I realize that when full this is about 2000 pounds right tight to my foundation wall on silty soil. I planned to build a solid platform (50x25inches or 127cmx64cm)  to spread the load a little but I am wondering if this is too much weight concentrated right next to my stem wall. All knowledge welcome. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have a sketch showing the design of your wall and where you plan to put these barrels?